# Google Doc Java API not returning file content

Tags: java, google-docs-api

I'm really struggling to read the content of a Google doc. I've followed all the API documentation on this and it just wont give me the content.

I've am able to locate the file by id and see all it's meta-data. But it continues to spit out some html or json presentation of the file meta-data as soon as I try and get an InputStream for the file content.

I have followed both https://developers.google.com/drive/web/manage-downloads 
and https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get.

What is interesting is that both File.getDownloadURL() and File.getExportLinks() for the file return null. Does that mean that the file content isn't available to download?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you provide the request and response here? Try using the Files.list resource instead. I tested with the Files.list (https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list) and both return successfully.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Upon close inspection of the response, it actually does have the spreadsheet in the http response content. The problem is that the response is text/html. I'm trying to get the response with the appropriate MIME type (according to `String downloadUrl = file.getExportLinks().get("application/pdf");` ).  But with `getExportLinks()` returning null, that doesn't seem to be possible. Here is a test doc I've made publicly available ([link]https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1auOz2tLbt4Bd8c-AQoDAlJ-_ke4hdFC05oFkhQj611E). Can anyone export that to EXCEL mime type with Java?

Comment: Ok so there may be a problem with the OAuth mechanism which I was originally following from the examples. I verified through the API key approach that, if you don't authenticate, the export links aren't available. So I just added an API key on the developers console and used that with a plain HTTP get to obtain the export links. Then downloaded the spreadsheet as xls with the relevant link.